# Unhandled Exception Error, Memory Violation

Tags: c++, string, class, pointers

My program crashes as soon as a new MyString object is created.

When the stringArray[0] is set to a null char in the constructor, I get a memory access violation. Any ideas?

Here is the constructor

```
MyString::MyString()
{
     stringSize = 0;
     stringCap = 16;
     stringArray[stringCap + 1];
     stringArray[0] = '\0';
}
```

Here is the classes private members

```
char* stringArray;
int stringCap;
int stringSize;
```

Here is the where the object is created in main.cpp

```
MyString s1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not allocate memory:

```
stringArray[stringCap + 1];
```

You need to replace it with:

```
stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];
```

Don't forget to delete the memory.

Also Rule of 3 applies here as you have RAW memory owned by the object.

Alternatively if you don;t want dynamic allocation but rather fixed size strings. Then you can change the declaration of your members:

```
char stringArray[ <FixedSizeHere> ];
```

Comment: Indeed. Just to add to what Martin said, the destructor of the class is where you should free the allocated memory: `MyString::~MyString() { delete stringArray; }`

Comment: @bluetickk It's important for all of us that you review the answers and accept the one that solved your problem, ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
char* stringArray;
```

Above statement says, `stringArray` is a pointer to character(s). So, it should hold the address of a character location.

```
stringArray[stringCap + 1];
```

Here you are trying to **access** the character located at index `stringCap+1` as if the `stringArray` is pointing to an array of characters. But `stringArray` is not holding any character's address location. Hence the error, of **memory access violation**.

If what you meant to create an array of size `stringCap+1`, it is also wrong.

```
stringArray[stringCap + 1];
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^  size of the array should be compile time constant.
          // i.e., integer literal, or a #defined constant or const int
```

It seems, program is trying to create the character array of size **17**. So, you can do that in class declaration it self -

```
class MyString
{
     stringArray[17] ;
     // .....
};
```